# How to convert strings to Num.num in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I'm looking for a function that converts a string representation of a decimal number into a `Num.num`. There is a `Num.num_of_string` function but, sadly, it only works for valid integers.

I'm asking before reimplementing one such function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do it yourself, I think. I did it once, here's what I did :

```
let num_of_string =
  let open Num in
  let code_0 = Char.code '0' in
  let num10 = Int 10 in
  fun s ->
    try num_of_string s 
    with Failure _ ->
      let r = ref (Int 0) in
      let pos_dot = ref (-1) in
      String.iteri (fun i c ->
        if c = '.' then pos_dot := String.length s - i 
        else
          r := add_num (mult_num num10 !r) (num_of_int (Char.code c - code_0))
      ) s;
      assert (!pos_dot <> -1);
      div_num !r (power_num num10 (num_of_int !pos_dot))
```